# Responsive two-column floated list

Tags: html, css, css-float, responsive-design, media-queries

Essentially what I am wanting to do is create some markup that allows me to resize the browser window and the contents of a `div` resize accordingly.

Here is what the layout should look like at a larger screen width:
[image: larger width]

Here is what the layout should look like at a skinnier screen width:
[image: skinnier width]

*The font sizes can all stay the same.*

What I'm having a hard time with is getting the layouts to change accordingly and also get the avatar to scale from 80px down to 50px when the width is shrunk.

I have my avatar image wrapped in

```
<div class="comments-avatar">
    <img src="#" />
</div>
```

The meta info and comment text are wrapped in

```
<div class="comments-content">
    <div class="comments-meta">
        <div class="comments-text"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The `.comments-avatar` class is floated left and the `.comments-content` is floated right.
Other than that, I'm assuming I need to use a CSS media query. I understand how to do that, I guess what I'm struggling with has something to do with needing to set percentages?

Any ideas to make this markup as simple as possible (even simpler than what I'm trying to do) would be GREATLY appreciated.

---

Here's what I have so far code-wise.  I'm not entirely happy with it.  Seems like more code than necessary...

## CSS:

```
#comments {
    padding: 20px 0 0 0;
    border-top: 1px solid @clr-1;

    ol.commentlist {
        margin: 35px 0 50px 0;
        padding: 0;
        list-style: none;

        li {
            padding: 0 0 52px 5px;

            .comment-avatar {
                width: 11%;
                min-width: 50px;
                float: left;
                padding: 0 10px 0 0;

                .avatar {
                    margin-top: -2px;
                    width: 100%;
                    height: auto;
                    min-width: 50px;
                    max-width: 80px;
                }
            }

            .comment-content {
                width: 100%;

                .comment-meta {
                    font-size: 1.8em;
                    padding: 4% 0;
                }

                > p {
                    margin: 22px 0;
        }
            }
        }
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width:961px) {
    .comment-content {
        width: 87%;
        float: right;
    }

    .comment-meta {
        padding: 0;
    }
}
```

## HTML:

```
<div id="comments">
    <ol class="commentlist">
        <li>
            <div class="comment-avatar">
                <img src="avatar/image/here.jpg" />
            </div>

            <div class="comment-content">
                <div class="comment-meta">
                    Posted on July 30, by admin.
                </div>

                <p>Paragraph text here...</p>
                <p>Paragraph text here...</p>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

Any thoughts anyone? This seems like too much of a hack-ish way of styling this.

Comment: Are you trying to use that for different device or just for PC?

Comment: Well, other devices ideally, but that is easy to support through a media query.  961px wide and up is the larger screenshot while the smaller screenshot is 320px wide.

Comment: I guess you can use JavaScript or jquery detecting window width to achieve that.

Comment: True, but I think what I am struggling with the most is the CSS side of things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using div's play with % inspite of px to define the size of the division. As % is relative to the screen and px are fixed in the context.

Answer (score 0):

This code should do what you need :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
    html,body{
        padding:0;
        margin:0;
    }

    .lpanel{
        float:left;
        width:50px;
        height:50px;
        background-color:red;
    }

    .rpanel{
        margin-left:50px;
    }

    @media screen and (max-width:400px){
        .rpanel{
            margin-left:0;
        }
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="lpanel">
  </div>
  <div class="rpanel">
            Some long text
      </div>
</body>
</html>
```